# Static inline method no need static member initialization

Tags: c++, static, inline

There is class:

*k.h*

```
class k
{
    static int ii;
    static void foo();
};
```

*k.cpp*

```
#include "k.h"

void k::foo()
{
    ii++;
}
```

During compile I get the following error message:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int k::ii" (?ii@k@@0HA)
```

It's OK. But when I add `inline` keyword to method, error is disappeared:

```
class k
{
    static int ii;
    inline static void foo();
};
```

This is not real-world example, but I don't know what exactly happens in this code, may be someone explain it to me?

Comment: Where is `foo` used? Where is `ii` defined? Where is `foo` defined?

Comment: @Charles Bailey foo nowhere used, ii nowhere defined, foo defined in cpp file. But I already get explanation in answer below, it seems totally correct. foo not used, therefore code for it is not generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct k
{
    static int ii;
    static void foo();
};

void k::foo() {
    ii=0;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

gives a linking error, because the function k::foo is output by the compiler, and it references k::ii.

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct k
{
    static int ii;
    inline static void foo();
};

inline void k::foo() {
    ii=0;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

does not give a linking error, because the function k::foo is declared inline and is not called from anywhere, so the compiler never actually produces any code for it.

If you add a call to k::foo() inside main, or anywhere else, then you will get a linking error.

Comment: In C++ you pay for what you use.

Comment: Thanks, sounds logical.